# parse error on alter table in MySQL using MAMP

Tags: mysql, mamp

I am using MAMP with MySQL server ver 5.5.42.

When I do an Alter table using phpMyAdmin on the MAMP server:

```
ALTER TABLE config DROP COLUMN 132
```

I get

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'config' DROP COLUMN 132' at line 1

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it should be:

```
ALTER TABLE `config` DROP COLUMN `132`
```

`--> the accent or backquote character on the tilde key. :|